# How do I use a soap xml based webservice in javascript over a secure https connection?

Tags: javascript, web-services, firefox, soap, firefox-addon

I want to use a XML SOAP web service in JavaScript to create a Firefox Addon, but the web service I want to use is under a secure https connection.

> https://cuotas.uci.cu:443/servicios/v1/InetCuotasWS.wsdl

The soapclient.js library that I downloaded doesn't work with a secure connection. How can I solve this problem? Are there any existing useful JS libraries?

EDIT:
This is what is shown in the link

```
<!-- WSDL file generated by Zend Studio. --><definitions name="InetCuotasWS" targetNamespace="urn:InetCuotasWS">
<types><xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:InetCuotasWS">
<xsd:complexType name="Usuario"><xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="cuota" type="xsd:float"/><xsd:element name="cuota_usada" type="xsd:anyType"/>
<xsd:element name="nivel_navegacion" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="usuario" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:all></xsd:complexType></xsd:schema></types>
<message name="ObtenerCuota"><part name="usuario" type="xsd:string"/><part name="clave" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="dominio" type="xsd:string"/></message>
<message name="ObtenerCuotaResponse"><part name="ObtenerCuotaReturn" type="typens:Usuario"/></message><portType name="InetCuotasWSPortType">
<operation name="ObtenerCuota"><documentation>
            Obtener el estado de la cuota de un usuario dado su usuario y clave.
        </documentation>
<input message="typens:ObtenerCuota"/>
<output message="typens:ObtenerCuotaResponse"/></operation></portType><binding name="InetCuotasWSBinding" type="typens:InetCuotasWSPortType">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="ObtenerCuota"><soap:operation soapAction="urn:InetCuotasWSAction"/><input><soap:body namespace="urn:InetCuotasWS" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input><output><soap:body namespace="urn:InetCuotasWS" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output></operation></binding><service name="InetCuotasWSService"><port name="InetCuotasWSPort" binding="typens:InetCuotasWSBinding"><soap:address location="https://cuotas.uci.cu/servicios/v1/InetCuotasWS.php"/>
</port></service></definitions>
```

EDIT
I used SoapUI as you said, this is the URI 
https://cuotas.uci.cu/servicios/v1/InetCuotasWS.php?wsdl
And SoapMessage is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:InetCuotasWS">
<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body>
<urn:ObtenerCuota soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<usuario xsi:type="xsd:string">dogcalas</usuario>
<clave xsi:type="xsd:string">.*Pepe</clave>
<dominio xsi:type="xsd:string">uci</dominio>
</urn:ObtenerCuota></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I send the soap message in Firefox, the alert('ERROR') is shown and Firefox´s firebug addon shows this message.

> Error de lectura XML: no se encuentra elemento Ubicación:
>   moz-nullprincipal:{fc98c066-ae21-4b57-b743-83e9519342c7} Número de
>   línea 1, columna 1:

Even using another service, Firefox always shows the same message.
Only when I use Internet Explorer 10, the message is sent, but the server response isn´t what I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>SoapClient::SoapClient() [&lt;a href='soapclient.soapclient'&gt;soapclient.soapclient&lt;/a&gt;]: 'location' and 'uri' options are required in nonWSDL mode</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In IE, if I use another service, the script works.

Comment: over javascript, unless the server supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), you would probably be stuck with a [CROSS-DOMAIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882522/crossdomain-error) error. **P.S.** The links goes nowhere.

Comment: ups, The link is just for my college

Comment: then you will have a big problem doing that plugin... ;)

Comment: I think that the server doesn´t need CORS because i will consume the service from the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concern about Cross-Domain, then you can give this a try... I'll use jQuery as it's way simpler, you would have to convert to your own syntax if you have to as I never did Mozilla Plugins.

**Note:** you need to get the correct **URL** for the call, and the correct **Soap Message**

For this, I would suggest you install [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) and connect to the service, you will get all raw information needed to send and receive information

```js
var webServiceURL = 'https://cuotas.uci.cu:443/servicios/v1/InetCuotasWS?op=ObtenerCuota';
var soapMessage = '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap12:Body><ObtenerCuota xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" /></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>';

function CallService()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: webServiceURL, 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml", 
        data: soapMessage, 
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success: OnSuccess, 
        error: OnError
    });

    return false;
}

function OnSuccess(data, status)
{
    alert(data.d);
}

function OnError(request, status, error)
{
    alert('error');
}

$(function() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
});
```